# What the -t switch means in dub init <name> -t vibe.d

Tags: d

I checked `man dub`, `dub help`, `dub help init`, but neither mentions the `-t` switch.

Comment: It is the type of the artefact your are building.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The online docs are a bit more complete:

http://code.dlang.org/docs/commandline

`-t` is the "type"

> Set the type of project to generate. Available types:
>
> minimal - simple "hello world" project (default)
>
> vibe.d - minimal HTTP server based on vibe.d
>
> deimos - skeleton for C header bindings